# Setting Multiple-Day notification with Powershell3

Tags: scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0

[Set-CalenderNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-calendarnotification?view=exchange-ps#:%7E:text=The%20Set%2DCalendarNotification%20cmdlet%20allows,calender%20events%20in%20user%20calendars.) provides a one time notification functionality with emails , but the notification is only restricted to one .

If one wants to set up a Multiple-Day  notification (similar to  [Task Scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10)  which outputs a GUI message prompt  on these  days) ,is there any command available in Powershell( other than settings it up entirely by polling the dates using the Get-Date cmdlet)?

Also,is there any way to access TaskScheduler as an Object with Powershell (inorder to use the  Multiple-Day  notification feature ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[New-ScheduledTaskTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger?view=win10-ps) creates a scheduled task trigger object,which provides the options to provide multiple day notification.

Syntax

```
New-ScheduledTaskTrigger
   [-RandomDelay <TimeSpan>]
   -At <DateTime>
   [-DaysOfWeek <DayOfWeek[]>]
   [-Weekly]
   [-WeeksInterval <UInt32>]
```

Example

```
New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -WeeksInterval 2 -DaysOfWeek Sunday -At 3am
```